# xfce4 applications popup is still bound to <Super> even after removing keybinding

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I use xfce4 as my desktop environment.
Setting `<Alt>F1` to `rofi -show drun` makes it so that pressing `<Super>` opens the `rofi` drun launcher, as I wanted. But it as also opening the popup applications menu.
To stop this from happening, I used the GUI settings editor to remove the default `<Alt>F1` keybinding binding it to `xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu`. It seems to have worked since now the only line in the output of `xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -lv` with `<Alt>F1` is the one with `rofi`.

However, pressing `<Super>` still brings up the xfce popup menu (as well as rofi's launcher). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the `Super_L` key was being mapped to both `Alt|F1` and `Ctrl|Esc` by a program called `xcape`, and `Ctrl|Esc` was bound to `xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu`.

Here is a description of how I found this out so that you can debug it yourself in case you're in a similar situation:

1. I noticed in my task manager two `xcape` processes performing the maps described above.
2. I searched (using `fd`) for files `xcape` in my root directory and its children directories. I found one file in `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/autostart` which was mapping `Super_L` to `Ctrl|Esc`. Deleting this file and rebooting solved my problem.